# Roaming Profiles Equivelent

Tags: server, users, user-management

I was in the process of setting up a network made up of 6 linux machines and 1 linux server, and I was wondering if there was a way to create user accounts that can be accessed from all machines without  having to create the accounts individually on each machine.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean in 'roaming'... But.
Here is a solution to your need:

[OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) as directory server
Linux client with [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/), [NSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) and the lpad client
Users `/home` folders can be created on each client machine at first logon of a user, or created on an NFS share on the server for full Roaming.
See those docs for more information
 - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication
 - https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Centralized_authentication_using_OpenLDAP
 - https://www.systutorials.com/39544/unified-linux-login-and-home-directory-using-openldap-and-nfsautomount/